# Codeigniter delete and update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete a transporteur and i have a an attribute in the database needs to change to 0

This attribute is assigned when adding a carrier and removes it must return to zero

thank you for helping me

**Model transporteur**

```
public function delete($email)
{
    $this->db->delete('transporteur', array('email' => $email));
}
```

**controlleur transporteur**

```
public function delete()
{
    $users = $this->transporteur_model->get_emails();

    $this->load->view('admin_delete_tr', array(
        'users' => $users
    ));
}

public function delete_user()
{
    sleep(1);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|max_length[40]|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $message = "<strong>suppression</strong> echoué!";
        $this->json_response(FALSE, $message);
    } else {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $this->transporteur_model->delete($email);

        $message = "<strong>".$email."</strong> a été supprimé!";
        echo json_encode(array(
            'isSuccessful' => TRUE,
            'message' => $message,
            'email' => $email
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: you code is not clear

Comment: yes sir i want a solution thank you for your reply

Comment: when you are deleting the row at the same time  you update the value to 0 for the field. also make these deletion and updation statements inside a transaction

Comment: to date this is good from 0 to 1 when I assign a truck driver 
but otherwise I did not find solution 
help me sir

Comment: I see that you want to delete from transporteur where email=$email but which field you want to update in which table ?

Comment: i which apdate in table camion

Comment: i'have teste this but no work :/
public function delete($email, id_camion)
    {
        $this->db->delete('transporteur', array('email' => $email));
        $this->db->where('cid', $id_camion);

        $this->db->update('camion', array('etat' => 0));
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a transaction. let me know if you get any error

```
public function delete($email, id_camion) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->delete('transporteur', array('email' => $email));
    $this->db->where('cid', $id_camion); 
    $this->db->update('camion', array('etat' => 0));
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: no error but not put a level of state
and other disturbances message "deleted carrier" does not appear despite supprission carrier.

Comment: please check the table name and field name are correct

Comment: there might be other problem

Comment: the problem that I am stuck in this step and I are Features months to complete my application